# Override inline element style for multiple DIVs

Tags: css

I need to override an inline element style for multiple DIVs. Long story short, I just need to do it on one page for a Wordpress plugin that loads on multiple pages.

Here's what I need help with:

`<div class="galleria-container notouch" style="width: 940px; height: 667px;"></div>`

In this example I need to change the height from 667px to 568px. This code is output by the WP plugin so I cannot change it on the page without messing up the rest of the site. I think I need to do it via JavaScript, but haven't had any luck yet getting it to work.

Comment: Can't you just target that class and override it in css for that particular page with !important?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

- a style like "display: block;" or "display: inline-block"
- a class holding the above styles

When other classes contradict on style "display", try to append "! important" or replace that classes by one with own display style.

```
 <div class="galleria-container notouch" 
      style="display: block ! important; width: 940px; height: 667px;"></div>
```

Comment: I need to override the style either in an external stylesheet or by using JavaScript. I cannot edit the code I've posted directly if that makes sense.

Comment: You can change the style sheet defining 'galleria-container' or 'notouch', or per javascript finding all elements using certain classes and add styles you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way using the Article ID from the main stylesheet:

```
article#page-16755 div.notouch[style] {height: 568px !important;}
```